# NLog.NET how to see target filename after reconfiguring target filename

Tags: .net, filenames, nlog

I need to read the target filename after reconfiguring it.

I successfully target a new filename with:

```
Logger log = LogManager.GetLogger( pLoggerName );
NLog.Targets.FileTarget target = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget();
target.Name = loggerName;
target.FileName = newLogPathFileName;       
NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration config = LogManager.Configuration;
config.AddTarget( loggerName, target );    
NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForFileLogging( newLogPathFileName, LogLevel.Debug 
LoggingRule rule = new LoggingRule( log.Name, LogLevel.Debug, target );
config.LoggingRules.Add( rule );
LogManager.Configuration = config;
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

At this point I see the logging in the new filename. Now,

log.Factory.Configuration.ConfiguredNamedTargets
still contains the old filename target.

I see the correct new filename target in the debugger, under
log._configuration._targetsByLevel

But _configuration and _targetsByLevel are not accessible at run time.

So how can I programatically verify the new target filename?  I need this to solve another bug where my loggers are logging into eachother's files.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are only using a single global FileTarget. Maybe just use [NLog GDC](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/GDC-Layout-Renderer) to store the filename:

```cs
    NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set(pLoggerName, newLogPathFileName);

    NLog.Targets.FileTarget target = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget();
    target.Name = pLoggerName;
    target.FileName = $"${{gdc:item={pLoggerName}}}";

    NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
    LoggingRule rule = new NLog.Config.LoggingRule(pLoggerName, LogLevel.Debug, target);
    config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
    NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Then you can lookup the current-filename like this:

```cs
    string fileName = NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Get(pLoggerName);
```

But if you are really eager to [lookup the filetarget](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configure-from-code#update-config-in-code), then you can do this:

```cs
   var fileTarget = NLog.LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<NLog.Targets.FileTarget>(pLoggerName);
   var fileName = fileTarget.FileName.Render(LogEventInfo.CreateNullEvent());
```